# Parameter's Value visibility

Tags: solidity, contract-development, privacy

Is the value of a contract's method's parameter visible on blockchain?
On Etherscan, in the tx information there is an Input Data field, which details says

> The binary data that formed the input of the transaction, either the input data if it was a message call or the contract initialisation if it was a contract creation

Is this what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that information is publicly available and is generated like this:

[Mastering Ethereum - Transmitting a Data Payload to an EOA or Contract](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#transmitting-a-data-payload-to-an-eoa-or-contract)

> When your transaction contains data, it is most likely addressed to a
>   contract address. That doesn’t mean you cannot send a data payload to
>   an EOA—that is completely valid in the Ethereum protocol. However, in
>   that case, the interpretation of the data is up to the wallet you use
>   to access the EOA. It is ignored by the Ethereum protocol. Most
>   wallets also ignore any data received in a transaction to an EOA they
>   control. In the future, it is possible that standards may emerge that
>   allow wallets to interpret data the way contracts do, thereby allowing
>   transactions to invoke functions running inside user wallets. The
>   critical difference is that any interpretation of the data payload by
>   an EOA is not subject to Ethereum’s consensus rules, unlike a contract
>   execution.
>
> For now, let’s assume your transaction is delivering data to a
>   contract address. In that case, the data will be interpreted by the
>   EVM as a contract invocation. Most contracts use this data more
>   specifically as a function invocation, calling the named function and
>   passing any encoded arguments to the function.
>
> The data payload sent to an ABI-compatible contract (which you can
>   assume all contracts are) is a hex-serialized encoding of:
>
> **A function selector**
>
> The first 4 bytes of the Keccak-256 hash of the function’s prototype. This allows the contract to unambiguously identify which
>   function you wish to invoke.
>
> **The function arguments**
>
> The function’s arguments, encoded according to the rules for the various elementary types defined in the ABI specification.
>
> In [solidity_faucet_example](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#solidity_faucet_example), we defined a function for withdrawals:
>
> ```
> function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public {
> ```
>
> The prototype of a function is defined as the string containing the
>   name of the function, followed by the data types of each of its
>   arguments, enclosed in parentheses and separated by commas. The
>   function name here is withdraw and it takes a single argument that is
>   a uint (which is an alias for uint256), so the prototype of withdraw
>   would be:
>
> ```
> withdraw(uint256)
> ```
>
> Let’s calculate the Keccak-256 hash of this string:
>
> ```
> > web3.sha3("withdraw(uint256)"); 
> '0x2e1a7d4d13322e7b96f9a57413e1525c250fb7a9021cf91d1540d5b69f16a49f'
> ```
>
> The first 4 bytes of the hash are 0x2e1a7d4d. That’s our "function
>   selector" value, which will tell the contract which function we want
>   to call.
>
> Next, let’s calculate a value to pass as the argument withdraw_amount.
>   We want to withdraw 0.01 ether. Let’s encode that to a hex-serialized
>   big-endian unsigned 256-bit integer, denominated in wei:
>
> ```
> > withdraw_amount = web3.toWei(0.01, "ether");
> '10000000000000000'
> > withdraw_amount_hex = web3.toHex(withdraw_amount);
> '0x2386f26fc10000'
> ```
>
> Now, we add the function selector to the amount (padded to 32 bytes):
>
> ```
> 2e1a7d4d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000
> ```
>
> That’s the data payload for our transaction, invoking the withdraw
>   function and requesting 0.01 ether as the withdraw_amount.